# Symbol similar to \mathcal{P}

Tags: symbols

I need to distinguish between the power set operation and a distinct, but similar operation, given the assumptions. For power set I use `\mathcal{P}`, as is standard. How may I obtain a symbol similar to `\mathcal{P}` by replacing the left protruding downward bending stroke with a horizontal line?

Comment: Do you have an image for example? I have not understood.

Comment: @Sebastiano I may post one tomorrow, as I have time again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user guide of the `mathalpha` package -- type `texdoc mathalpha` at a command prompt to load its user guide in a pdf viewer -- lists lots and lots of math-caligraphic and math-script fonts; see pp. 8 thru 10 of the user guide.

Maybe something like the following example, which uses the "euler" and "cm" math fonts, works for you. If not, do please indicate what you prefer instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{P} \quad \mathcal{P}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! For some reason I got the P of rsfso (which is the second mentioned as a standard symbol by Wikipedia), and not, as with you, that of euler, and its kins. But it serves. :)