# Alternative power symbol with newtxtext and newtxmath?

Tags: symbols

Confer this question: [Symbol similar to \mathcal{P}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699976/symbol-similar-to-mathcalp/699989#699989)

With this mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
    $\mathscr{P}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

the desired alternative symbol for power set is obtained,

but not with the following one which realistically includes \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=euler]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\begin{document}
    $\mathscr{P}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

How may one obtain the desired power set symbol of the first mwe in the presence of \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}?

Comment: Change the loading order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you run `\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=euler]{mathalpha}` after rather than before `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage[scr=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
    $\mathscr{P}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's swell! :)